# mysql - View code of stored procedure but get truncated definition

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So, I need to modify a stored procedure and I want to look at the old code.

I have tried both:

```
show create procedure [myProcedureNameHere];
select routine_definition from information_schema.routines where routine_name = '[myProcedure]';
```

in both cases I get the beginnings of the defining code, but eventually it putters out with an ellipsis ( . . .)
one returns:

```
CREATE DEFINER='CodingForFunAndProfit@10.0.0.1' PROCEDURE 'myProcedureName'() begin select myColumnName as 'Bidpty Dipty', round(numbe...
```

and the other:

```
begin select myColumnName as 'Bidpty Dipty', round(numberCol,0) as wellRounde...
```

how can I get the rest of my definition?
(using MySQL Workbench, if the GUI matters.)

I'm guessing that it's something to do with some kind of column width limit, because the second one returns more of the procedure than the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which tool do you use actually for running these queries? If it were MySQL Workbench (judgin from the set tags) then I don't know where you see this text output actually.

You can get this much easier however: using MySQL Workbench open a connection and then in the left sidebar (the schema tree) right click on your procedure and select "Alter Procedure". This will open an object editor with the procedure's text and more. You can edit the code and apply it when you are done.

Comment: Simple answers are always the best answers.

But, to answer your question, I just run the select or the show from a query editor tab, and the output I have listed is displayed directly below it, in the results window.  Just like any other query.

Comment: Ok, you probably mean the resultset grid. You can right click on the cell with the text and in the context menu there's a "Open Value in Editor" which opens a dedicated editor showing the value as text, hex or image.